# Detecting if a variable is global or not

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to detect weither or not a variable is defined globally inside from inside a function scope?

Comment: Nice question. Code inspection? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `in` against the global object.

```
'myvar' in window
```

For example...

```
alert( 'setTimeout' in window ); // true
```

Comment: I'd forgotten the `in` operator could be used like this. Thank you sir.

Comment: That doesn't help when `myvar` is shadowed in the function.

Comment: @thg435: Not sure why it would matter where you run it, as long as you have access to the global object... unless I'm misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I really don't understand, why the var needs to be quoted... but it's the only way, how it's working?!

Comment: @Christoph: The `in` operator allows you to ask any object if it has a property. So if I have an object `var x = { foo:123 };`, I can ask the `x` object if it has the `'foo'` property. `'foo' in x; // true` So the first argument is a string, because all properties are ultimately represented as strings, and so we're asking if the object has a property that matches that string. The `.hasOwnProperty()` method is similar, and passing a string probably looks more familiar. `x.hasOwnProperty('foo')`

Comment: ...by the way, if you try `window.hasOwnProperty('setTimeout')`, it may be `false` because `hasOwnProperty` doesn't search the prototype chain like `in` does.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( typeof window.myvar != "undefined") { /* variable is global */ }
else { /* variable is local */ }
```

Comment: This will only tell you if a global var exists with the same name as the local var, it won't tell you that the var you're dealing with _is_ the global.

Comment: Hmm... In that case the closest would be to add `&& window.myvar === myvar`, but if they happen to have the same value you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The global object in a browser environment is always
    window
. So you may check, whether
    window['yourprop']
exists, to see whether it is global.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 1;
(function() {
  var b = 2;
}());

alert(window.a);
alert(window.b);
```

Like that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using `window.variable === variable` ? For example:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 5;

function tst()
{
    var a = 4;
    alert(a === window.a); // Returns false because 'a' is local
    alert(b === window.b); // Returns true because 'b' is global
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign something "unique" to window[varName] and then test if the actual value matches:

```
varName = "myvar"
isGlobal = false
test = "some unique string"

savedValue = window[varName]
window[varName] = test

try {
    isGlobal = eval(varName + "==='" + test + "'")
} catch(e) {}

window[varName] = savedValue
```

`isGlobal` will be `true` if `myvar` is global and not shadowed in the current scope.

Comment: @Christoph: there's no other way to answer this question.

Comment: If you are serious about that, quit programming!

Comment: @Christoph: hey bro, hard Monday isn't it ;)

Comment: I hate mondays -.- Don't take it seriously;)